# When use 'new', what's the difference between returning the pointer by reference or by pointer itself?

Tags: c++, reference, return

In c++, when I use "new"in a function, a pointer will be created.
Then, when I consider to return the result of function, what's the difference among by reference and by pointer?

like:

BY Reference

```
Sample& (int & x, int & y){
    Sample * temp = new Sample(x,y);
    return *temp;
}
```

BY Pointer itself

```
Sample* (int & x, int & y){
    Sample * temp = new Sample(x,y);
    return temp;
}
```

It seems that memory leak would be caused when use 'new' improperly, does memory leak would happen in these situations above? Or there will be some risk in the future when reuse these return materials?

Comment: The difference is that with the first you have to call `delete &obj`, with the second `delete obj`, where `obj` is the returned object.

Comment: Yeah, what's you said is really the difference.

Comment: You are not returning a pointer by reference. You are returning a reference to a the object the pointer points to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you return a reference, it implies to the caller that they don't need to `delete` the returned object, leading to memory leak.  The implication is even stronger if they just look at your API and not the function implementation.

Using a smart pointer is the recommended way to let the caller know the object is dynamically allocated and they should cooperate in its lifetime management.  Returning *by value* is even better when there's no compelling reason to do otherwise.

Comment: someone says by value results in a copy which is not so efficient. by the way, is there any problem by returning a local variable by reference?

Comment: copying a pointer, in the cases where the compiler can't put it in the right place directly, is a single instruction. Using a reference to the object will cause extra work when referncing "sample" which is hidden from view.  You may also, of course, end up accdentally writing code that copies the actual `Sample` - such as `Sample s = obj(x, y);` instead of `Sample& s = obj(x,y);` [also, don't use `int &x, int &y` - there is no benefit, and it probably will make the code slower and larger - and you can't do `obj(x+3, y+8);` unless you add `const`, but for `int` reference isn't needed]

Comment: @Johnn: There are two ways in which that inefficient copy are remedied. The first is by the optimizer removing the copy altogether, and the second is by moving the return value instead of copying it.

Comment: I would prefer using a smart pointer - the rules for return-value optimization and copy elision are complex and do not give absolute guarantees that a copy will not be made.

Comment: @Johnn; MSalter's points about the real-world efficiency of return by value are valid - it's rarely an issue.  Regarding your question *"any problem by returning a local variable by reference"* - yes, huge problems as the memory for local variables is on the stack, the destructors (if any) run as the enclosing scope (the `for`, `if`. `while`, or `{ }`-block) is left, and that memory is very likely to be reused shortly afterwards for other local variables and/or function calls.  Your choices are dynamically-allocated, by value, references/pointers to statics/globals, memory mapped/shared mem.